# Update row Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Windows Azure Mobile Services (c# Win RT application).
When clicked on a button I would like to update some columns from a specific row (Id).

```
var person = new Bettie { Id = 5, Score = 4, Score2 = 3 };
await todoTable.UpdateAsync(person);
```

But everytime I do this the other columns update to Null in my table. How can I just update the columns I want and leave the other columnvalues like before?

Comment: By other columns are you referring to Score and Score2?

Comment: I have about 10 columns in my table: Id, Name, Team, Sport, Score, Score2, .... But I only want to change the values from Score and Score2. When I check my table I see Name, Team, Sport has null as value and Score = 4 and Score2 = 3. I don't want that the other columns change to value null.